# update child view textview in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm working on an app using storyboard and Navigation controller is embedded in. In the child view, when a button is pressed, it calls a function in parent view controller without changing the view.

```
[self.delegate buttonPressed];
```

and the method supposed to update the text of textview in child view.
    childviewcontroller.textViewName.text=@"something";
But the textview is not being updated.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}
```

Long story short is, if I want the parent view controller to change the text of a textview in child view controller, how should I set it up when I'm using storyboard. 
Can anyone give me some ideas?
I don't know if I explain it clearly or not. I'm still kinda new to this and am learning while making this app. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds confusing.  If you are needing to fire off a function in the parent VC, why not create a class method that returns what you need and then do something like this in that child VC:

```
NSString *newText = [MyParentViewController getSomeData];
myTextView.text = newText;
```

OR even better, put that class method in a new class that gets data for your VC's. This would be more in-line with object oriented programming.

Comment: It will be complicated to do in my app. I'm working with external hardware that I have to use a library provided by a iPhone cable company. Long story short is, if I want the parent view controller to change the text of a textview in child view controller, how should I set it up when I'm using storyboard.